# Finding reasons/rules for prediction

Tags: machine-learning, classification, prediction

I am new to machine learning. I have a requirement, I want to predict value of an attribute that has 2 values (Y and N) for which I am using classification model. I have 10-15 features to create the model. During prediction, I want to tell why (rules) I am making that prediction. If I use decision tree algorithm I am able to see some rule, but if I use other classification algorithms like SVM or Naive Bayes I am not able to find any rule.

I have 2 questions:
1. Is there any way to find rules for all algorithm?
2. Is this an uncommon requirement?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot find rules for all algorithms; many do not extract in simple forms.  For instance, the "Gaussian kernel trick" in SVM and the intermediate layers in a neural network do not lend themselves to easily-read rules.

No, requiring the decision algorithm in human-readable form is uncommon: most of the time, we don't care, because we are not going to compute the results ourselves.  Instead, we save the trained model (of whatever type / algorithm) and deploy it for general use.  We don't need to "look inside the box" to see the details of the answer.

In fact, for a CNN (or any but the simplest neural networks), that answer is so computationally complex that it's pretty much useless to a human mind: there are too many parameters and non-linear parts.